# Specifying HTTP referer in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, http-referer

How can we set HTTP referer in embedded UIWebView?

I had gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913305/specifying-http-referer-in-embedded-uiwebview) but still not got success.

**1.** In `viewDidLoad`, I wrote this code,

```
[objWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_URL"]]];
```

**Here is my code :**

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType) navigationType 
{
    NSDictionary *headers = [request allHTTPHeaderFields];
    BOOL hasReferer = [headers objectForKey:@"Referer"]!=nil;
    if (hasReferer) {
        // .. is this my referer?
        return YES;
    } else {
        // relaunch with a modified request
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSURL *url = [request URL];
                NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                [request setValue:@"Referer link" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Referer"];
                [objWebView loadRequest:request];
            });
        });
        return NO;
    }
}
```

**2.** I had tried this also in `viewDidLoad`

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_URL"]];
[request setValue:@"Referel URL" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Referer"];
[objWebView loadRequest:request];
```

But doesn't got success yet.

Please help me solve this problem or tell me is there any problem with this code or not?

Hope I presented question clearly.

Comment: Have you tried directly modifying the request passed to you (instead of launching a new one)?

Comment: It worth noting that you are relying on scope to distinguish two distinct variables both called `request` (a block has access to it's parent scope). In other words, you have a variable called `request` in scope, and then create another version of it. It's not exactly wrong, but can be confusing and degrades readability/maintainability

Comment: @ctrahey Please see my updated question.. Can plz tell me what is wrong with this and give me any suggestion for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set Default User-Agent using following code

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Safari/528.16", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

It is well explained [here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/06/radar-allow-overriding-of-user-agent-on-uiwebview/).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly is your situation. But for me, simply just setting `baseURL` parameter in `-loadHTMLString:baseURL:;` will automatically add HTTP header `Referer` as `baseURL` to all outgoing request under the HTML page.